# send more than one product details to mail in android using javamail api

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail, sendmail

I have to develop one android example.

More than one item details send to mail from my android application using javamail api.

Here i have to run the app means the latest added product alone send to mail.but i have to send the all added product detail is send to email.How can i do.please help me.whats wrong in my code.please check the code and give me solution for these.

I have used below code:

```
 public class InvoiceOrder extends Activity {


String mGrandTotal;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.invoice);
    ListView mLstView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);


    CustomerAdapter mViewCartAdpt = new CustomerAdapter(
            InvoiceOrder.this);
    mLstView1.setAdapter(mViewCartAdpt);

            Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mBtnSubmit);
            login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                    "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("krishnaveniv96@gmail.com","xxxxxx");
                    }
                });

            try {

                Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("krishnaveni.veeman@gmail.com"));
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        InternetAddress.parse("mercy.krishnaveni@gmail.com"));
                message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();                  
              //  message.setContent("This is your product name : "+
                    //    "Hi Krishna" +"<br></br>This is your price : "+ "Hi veni", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
                for (int i = 0; i < Constants.mItem_Detail
                        .size(); i++) {

                    String title = Constants.mItem_Detail
                            .get(i).get(
                                    SingleMenuItem.KEY_PNAME);

                    String qty = Constants.mItem_Detail.get(i)
                            .get(SingleMenuItem.KEY_QTY);

                    String cost = Constants.mItem_Detail.get(i)
                            .get(SingleMenuItem.KEY_PRICE);

                    String total = Constants.mItem_Detail
                            .get(i).get(
                                    SingleMenuItem.KEY_TOTAL);

                message.setContent("<tr>" + "<td>" + title
                            + "</td><td>" + qty + " * " + cost
                            + "</td>" + " = <td>" + total
                            + "  " + "</td></tr>", "text/html; charset=utf-8"); 

                }

                Transport.send(message);

                System.out.println("Done");

            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
           }



  });
```

**EDIT**:

```
                try {

                Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("krishnaveni.veeman@mercuryminds.com"));
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        InternetAddress.parse("mercy.krishnaveni@gmail.com"));
                message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
                //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();     
                StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();

                body.append("<html><body><table>");


              //  message.setContent("This is your product name : "+
                    //    "Hi Krishna" +"<br></br>This is your price : "+ "Hi veni", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
                for (int i = 0; i < Constants.mItem_Detail
                        .size(); i++) {

                    String title = Constants.mItem_Detail
                            .get(i).get(
                                    SingleMenuItem.KEY_PNAME);

                    String qty = Constants.mItem_Detail.get(i)
                            .get(SingleMenuItem.KEY_QTY);

                    String cost = Constants.mItem_Detail.get(i)
                            .get(SingleMenuItem.KEY_PRICE);

                    String total = Constants.mItem_Detail
                            .get(i).get(
                                    SingleMenuItem.KEY_TOTAL);

                    body.append("<tr>" + "<td>" + title
                            + "</td><td>" + qty + " * " + cost
                            + "</td>" + " = <td>" + total
                            + "  " + "</td></tr>");
                }

                body.append("<tr>" + "<td>" + "Grand Total is:-  "
                        + "</td><td>" + mGrandTotal + " "
                        + "</td></tr>");
                body.append("</table></body></html>");
            message.setContent(body);
             Transport.send(message);                   
        System.out.println("Done");

            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
           }
```

I have changed the code like above.here i have to get the below error:

The method setContent(Multipart) in the type Part is not applicable for the arguments (StringBuilder)

on these line message.setContent(body);

How can i clear these error.please help me.how can i send the more than one product detail is send to mail from my android application using javamail api.

Comment: Are you clear data from your Hashmap object anywhere?

Comment: no...here am not clear data anywhere????  here my view cart list have more product in listview.the listview have last product detail only sent to mail.but i have to send all viewcart product details to mail.

Comment: Please check the size of your added products list.

Comment: i have checked my added product list on view cart page.public int getCount() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return Constants.mItem_Detail.size();
 }

Comment: what is the size of your hashmap?

Comment: the size is dynamically added from my xml feed parser.